# How to fix “Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2?

Tags: maven

I have tried all of the above solutions but still seeing this error.
I have installed maven 3.5.3 ,JDK1.7.0_67 and eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2 and have configured maven in eclipse IDE

But when creating a maven project i see the below mentioned  error.

I tried resolving this

1. By updating the proxy setting in settings.xml file, but same error occurs.
2. By deleting the .m2 file and creating project again , but same error occurs.
3. By adding this maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar external jar

**None** of the above methods worked for me

Could you please help me in resolving this as I am Stuck here.

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 from
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 from/to
>   central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar.
>   Error code 503, Service Unavailable Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 from
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 from/to
>   central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar.
>   Error code 503, Service Unavailable